# How to save urllib python3 cookies to a file

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, urllib, cookiejar

Trying to store/re-use cookies *between code-executions*, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030095/how-to-save-requests-python-cookies-to-a-file), **but using only python3's `urllib`**.

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61213103/10761353) for the process for creating a cookiejar for automatic use across `urllib.request.Request` calls:

```
cookie_jar = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie_jar))
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
```

Initial searches on cookie storage led to SO questions regarding `requests` (the module)  + cookies, but unfortunately, `http.cookiejar` objects cannot be pickled (below), as opposed to their `requests` brethren, which *can*:

```
>>> pickle.dumps(cookie_jar)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

The other queries' results mostly pointed back the python3 docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html#http.cookiejar.FileCookieJar

Playing around with the `FileCookieJar` class led to noticing in the description: `A CookieJar which can load cookies from, and *perhaps* save cookies to, a file on disk.` and the associated error:

```
>>> FCJ=cookiejar.FileCookieJar("unversioned.cookies")              
>>> FCJ.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/cookiejar.py", line 1785, in save
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

Both of which were clarified by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10000170/10761353) - which suggested using [LWPCookieJar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html#http.cookiejar.LWPCookieJar) (among others) instead, but I couldn't find any existing examples on how to use this class in practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LWPCookieJar was the answer:

1. Create the CookieJar + try loading from any existing cookie file:

```py
cookie_filename = "unversioned.cookies"
cookie_jar = cookiejar.LWPCookieJar(cookie_filename)
try:
    cookie_jar.load()
except FileNotFoundError as fnfe:
    # No existing/adjacent cookie file
    pass

opener = request.build_opener(request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie_jar))
request.install_opener(opener)
```

2. complete any `urllib.request.Request` call that populates cookies
3. store the cookies to file (named in the constructor):

```py
cookie_jar.save()
```

And to confirm, after having saved some cookies in a previous execution-run:

1. prepare the cookiejar, but *do not* call `.load()`
2. test-request the page -> logged-out version received
3. call `cookiejar.load()`
4. test-request the page -> *logged-in* version received